# Nearest Neighbour Subquery in Presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I'm using Presto 329 and am trying to rewrite the following cross join to be more efficient by replacing the CROSS join for what is effectively an inner query for each row:

```sql
SELECT
    a.store_id,
    min(great_circle_distance(a.latitude, a.longitude,
        CAST(b.latitude AS double), CAST(b.longitude AS double))) AS distance
FROM store_location a
CROSS JOIN places_of_interest b
GROUP BY a.store_id;
```

For an explanation, `store_location` contains locations of buildings, and `places_of_interest` contains specific coordinates of popular tourist attractions. I want to find the closest tourist attraction to each store - a nearest neighbour problem.

I've been diving into the world of Presto sub-queries but without much luck. I've tried various combinations of subqueries and LATERAL, all around the theme of the below snippet, but without success.

```sql
SELECT a.store_id,
       (SELECT b.poi_id,
               great_circle_distance(a.latitude, a.longitude,
                   CAST(b.latitude AS double), CAST(b.longitude AS double)) AS distance
        FROM places_of_interest
        ORDER BY 2
        LIMIT 1) AS b (poi_id, distance)
FROM store_location a
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You are not going to be able to rewrite the query to be more efficient, just by manipulating the operations.  Unfortunately, the logic as you have described it requires comparing each store to each point of interest.

One option would be to have a threshold -- say 10 miles or 100 kilometers or whatever.  Instead of storing just the point of each geo point, store a "circle" with that point at the center.  Then look for overlaps before doing the sort.

This should reduce the amount of data needed for the subquery (or join).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did that with the original CROSS JOIN but it only made a 20s difference to a 6 minute runtime, which I thought was interesting. I might dig into why that is.

Comment: @BenWatson . . . Reduce the distance allowed for overlap.  That should increase performance.